# Difference between Euclidean Space and $\mathbb{R}^n$ other than origin?

Tags: geometry, soft-question

Often it is said that *Euclidean $n$-dimensional space over $\mathbb{R}$ is different from $\mathbb{R}^n$,  because in Euclidean space, all points are equivalent, in $\mathbb{R}^n$, there is origin.*

When I *just heard* this first time, I thought that the point $0$ is different from others in $\mathbb{R}^n$ when one concerns *algebra*: it is identity element (of a group/vector space/...). Otherwise,...possibly no problem. Why it is not correct to say $\mathbb{R}^n$ as Euclidean space?

Some books on Geometry also have some discussion or remarks on such topic ([see this](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=qwuGfirgwJcC&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=another%20role%20which%20%20plays%20is%20that%20%20...%20William%20Munger%20Boothby&source=bl&ots=aRRP9d2GtS&sig=OYFPW2iHQc2uMPQl0JLhuT3d2eI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMIweaAu5ycyQIVgZuUCh2rVwpZ#v=onepage&q=another%20role%20which%20%20plays%20is%20that%20%20...%20William%20Munger%20Boothby&f=false)).

Even in some of my lectures, when I wrote

> *Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ denotes Euclidean space...*,

some experts (from Geometry) said *''don't say $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or $\mathbb{R}^n, \langle\,\, ,\,\,\rangle$)as Euclidean space''.*

Is it not correct to teach Euclidean geometry by starting like this-

> Consider vector space (set) $\mathbb{R}^n$ with dot product.
>
> We say it is Euclidean space.
>
> Points in it are $n$-tuples.
>
> Lines are cosets of $1$-dimensional subspaces $x+W$.
>
> Two lines $x+W$ and $y+W'$ are orthogonal if $W,W'$ are orthogonal.

(and so on, ....). Whats *serious problems* come if we teach geometry like this?

Comment: If the last section is not correct, can we start as **Without loss of generality, let $\mathbb{R}^n$ with dot product denote Euclidean $n$-space. Points in it are .....**

Answer (score 3):

You can see it in this way: it's a matter of choosing coordinate system. Formally, an Euclidean space $\bf{E}$ is a metric vector space; when we want to make computations over $\bf{E}$, we may like to choose a basis for the underlying vector space. Or, in other words, we are using the (non-canonical) isomorphism $\mathbf{E}\simeq\mathbb{R}^n$.

Saying that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an Euclidean space is not completely wrong, it only assumes that you have chosen a basis for the underlying vector space.

Comment: So what would be appropriate word for $\mathbb{R}^n$ which includes Euclidean? Possibly can we say - *Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ denote n-dim. affine Euclidean space* or *let $\mathbb{R}^n$ denote (n-dim. affine Euclidean space)+(coordinates)*?

Comment: Usually I think of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a vector space "with euclidean [or also metric] structure" when I want to emphasize the fact that I'm using it as representation of euclidean space. I think, perhaps, that it's a bit sophistic to note such details, unless you're working on something where the difference is crucial.